# Does simple_salesforce handle refreshing sessions for you?

Tags: python, authentication, jwt, salesforce, simple-salesforce

At the moment, I have a Python app that's making API calls to Salesforce using the [simple_salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce) SDK. I'm using basic auth at the moment, and occasionally hit Salesforce's [limit](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381578&type=1) of 3,600 logins per hour.

My question is, if I were to move to a [JWT](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce?tab=readme-ov-file#examples) method of authentication, would the simple_salesforce SDK handle refreshing the session for me automatically? Or, would I need to store the session ID on my end, and fetch another session once that's expired?

I can see that support for "automatic session refresh" was [added](https://simple-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#features-2) in version 1.12.5, but I'm a little unsure if this feature is exactly what I'm hoping it to be.